# Laravel admin login isn't working

Tags: php, laravel

Admin login don't work and don't give me any error.

I have this routes in web.php file:

```
Auth::routes();


Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/login','Auth\AdminLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
    Route::post('/login','Auth\AdminLoginController@login')->name('admin.login.submit');
    Route::get('/','AdminController@getIndex')->name('admin.dashboard');
    Route::get('/logout','Auth\AdminLoginController@logout')->name('admin.logout');
    Route::post('/password/email','Auth\AdminForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('admin.password.email');
    Route::get('/password/reset','Auth\AdminForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('admin.password.request');
    Route::post('/password/reset','Auth\AdminResetPasswordController@reset');
    Route::get('/password/reset/{token}','Auth\AdminResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('admin.password.reset');

});
```

And this functions in controller(I only put here which have the problems)

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    return view('auth.adminlogin');
}
public function login(Request $request)
{
    //validate the form data
    $this->validate($request, [
           'email' => 'required|email',
           'password' => 'required|min:6'
    ]);
    //attempt to log the user in
    if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember)){
            //if successful, then redirect to their intended location
            return redirect('/admin');
    }
    return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email','remember'));
}
```

And in resources/views/auth/adminlogin.blade.php i have this code:

```
@extends('backend.public.includes.head')
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">ADMIN Login</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.login.submit') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Remember Me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Login
                                </button>

                                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('admin.password.request') }}">
                                    Forgot Your Password?
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

This was working days ago.. and now not, i'm looking all but don't find the error. In networking isn't showing anything and with a debug i don't see anything.

I try to reset password and when i reset it (i have a redirect in the function he redirect me good, only not working in normal login).

Errors aren't showed too

**EDIT**
Migrate file:

```
 public function up()
 {
        Schema::create('admins', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name',50)->unique();
            $table->string('email',200)->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->boolean('public')->default(true);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
 }
```

Seed file:

```
private $arrayAdmins = array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Lluis',
            'email' => 'lluis.puig@correo.biz',
            'password' => 'correo1',
            'public' => 1
        )
    );
 public function run()
    {
        self::seedAdmins();
    }

    public function seedAdmins()
    {
        DB::table('admins')->delete();
        foreach ($this->arrayAdmins as $admin)
        {
            $a = new Admin;
            $a->name = $admin['name'];
            $a->email = $admin['email'];
            $a->password = $admin['password'];
            $a->public = $admin['public'];
            $a->save();
        }
    }
```

The admin login isn't working if i created with the seed. (So the problem i guess is with the "user created" with the seed.

I try to create one with php artisan tinker and it works.

**SOLVED**

I check the seed. The problem was de password isn't encrypted!

This line :

$a->password = $admin['password'];

Must be like this:

$a->password = bcrypt($admin['password']);

Comment: So what happens when you try to log in? "_This was working days ago.. and now_" .. probably something was changed that's why it doesn't work right now.

Comment: I forget the "not". Nothing happens, just clear me the inputs and don't make the login. Sure, it's my fault.. but don't know what i change and make this don't work.. @AntonisTsimourtos

Comment: Well, personally i would edit the `login()` function and comment everything inside it. Use an `echo` to be sure it actually goes to that function. Have you tried running `php artisan clear:cache` ? or clearing the cache/routing generally

Comment: I make the `php artisan cache:clear` and i return the $request in controller, it pass the token, email and password :l

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean. It pass the token, email and password, you mean it didn't go into the `this->validate()` line?

Comment: I have more info. Check the bottom of the question please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150149/discussion-between-lluis-puig-ferrer-and-antonis-tsimourtos).